# How to manage pom.xml versions in git repository?

Tags: git, gitlab, pom.xml

I'm working on a large Java project with lots of developers. We use Gitlab as repository. Right now every developer submitting a merge request have to update the project version in pom.xml before making a commit. 
The problem happens when two developers work at different things and make two unrelated MRs at the same time, both with the same updated version number. First MR is merged correctly and second merge shows no conflict (version numbers in pom.xml are the same), so it is also merged. We now have two MRs merged with the same version number. It causes a problem when builds are uploaded to artifactory.

How to solve this issue?

I was thinking that every developer might append some ID (developer's initials for example) to the version number, forcing the conflict in the above scenario. Or maybe use a hook to automate updating the pom.xml version, so developers don't have to.

What the correct way to update project version number for every MR ?

Comment: I think you don't know about git well, because it is manage automatically if developer has their own accounts in gitlab

Comment: I suggest to you create different branches for the each feature of project

Comment: You may want to look into using a continuous integration tool like Jenkins or Bamboo.  These CI tools can manage your version numbers for you.

Comment: We create different branches for every feature, how else would we make MRs?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be overthinking the versioning in your team. I've seen such scheme before - people were suffering all the time. You can't fix this problem with Git, so just stop changing Maven's version - instead change the way you upload your artifacts.

If you're trying to implement CD in your company - a good way of versioning is using *resolved* SNAPSHOTs. Just keep the x.y.z-SNAPSHOT version and don't change x.y.z. When Maven uploads artifacts it creates a timestamp+number version which can be uniquely identified, e.g. `1.1.0-20190830.184736-6123`.

NB: by default each module is going to have its own timestamp. To use the same version across all the modules you could manually generate it and assign it with `mvn versions:set`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that while in development you are not complety sure what will go into a release.

I have seen the role of release manager. He is the one that decides when and to what version the release will be deployed. Also, developers work in feature branches, so if two developers work in the same feature they should work on the same branch.

There are several branching models out there. There are 4 in this [link](https://medium.com/@patrickporto/4-branching-workflows-for-git-30d0aaee7bf#targetText=During%20the%20development%20cycle%2C%20a,an%20undesired%20status%20of%20master%20.)

But there are companies that uses their own branching model due to their own release cycle.

My advice: check branching models, analyze your release cycle and implement any change according to your findings. After that, think moving to a CI/CD solution as this [Tim Biegeleisen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1863229/tim-biegeleisen) stated